# How to Bind a LineSeries' ItemSource to a PointCollection with IsAsync="True"?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

As the topic states, I want to Bind the data in a LineSeries to a PointCollection that I create, fill and mantain in Code-Behind through a Timer.
I have some success with the simple approach:

```
<charting:LineSeries.ItemsSource>
    <PointCollection x:Name="pntCLeftHand"/>
</charting:LineSeries.ItemsSource>
```

And then Adding items into 'pntCLeftHand' in Code-Behind.

This works well, but I think the UI Updating is just too time consuming, so I want the Binding to be Asynchronous. The IsAsync property would help me, but I guess this can only be used with something like the following:

```
<charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding pntCLeftHand, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

Unfortunately that just doesn't work.

Can somebody show me the way?

Thanks in advance.